# Infinite scroll start function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I have been trying to trigger some events when infinite scroll starts loading new items however, it triggers events but it won't load new items ( totally stops responding ) but it works fine when **start** option is removed.

they have an in-build function called **finished** which triggers as soon as infinite scroll done loading new items which works fine.

[docs](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/)

[docs2](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll)

```
$container.infinitescroll({
    loading: {
        finished: function() {
            alert("finished"); //works fine
        },
        start: function() {
          alert("started"); //triggers but breaks everything else.
        }
    },
    navSelector: "#next:last",
    nextSelector: "#next:last",
    itemSelector: ".post-item",
    debug: true,
    dataType: 'html',
    maxPage: 10,
    bufferPx: 300
}, function(newElements, data, url){
    //done

});
```

Comment: `navSelector` and `nextSelector` both are pointing to the same element, is that intentional?

Comment: @Anand I altered the code above to make it simple. Yes, I'm using a custom path so I really don't use make use of navSelector and nextSelector.

Comment: Setup a jsfiddle for someone to take a look.